# Google+ API read only - what is inserting a moment?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

Ok, so on the front page of the google plus api, it clearly states that the API is for read only for public data.

If that's true, then what does it mean to insert a moment? When I read through the moments documentation, it seems like it's an API to allow writing to google plus. Am I missing something?

Asking because I've been attempting to use the ReviewAction moment API to post a review, but have not been successful. My code seems to be working and I'm receiving no error messages, but the review will not show up on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moments are mostly used to inform Google when a users performs an action on your app/site. The are not Google+ posts so they do not show up on a Google+ stream.

One example use would be a movie review site. Each time a user watches a movie create a moment visible to their circles and when they review a movie create a moment visible publically. When another user signs into your app you can get a list of moments from Google from their circles and use it to build a timeline of activity.

[More details about how App Activities are used](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities).